# PHP Error During Addition of PHP Extension

Tags: php, mysql

I got this error upon checking the php_mssql extension on my wamp server:

```
Could not execute menu item (internal error)
[Exception] Could not perform service action:
The requested control is not valid for this service
```

How do I uncheck the php_mssql extension in my wamp server?

Comment: This does not have the format of a PHP error. Furthermore, you mention *php_mssql* but tag says *mysql*. Can you clarify the question or add more information?

Comment: Is you port 80 blocked? May be *Skype* or other version of *Apache* or *IIS*

Comment: I have two server running, a mssql server and a wamp server. but it was perfectly working fine until i checked the php_mssql extension on my wamp server. im also using port 8000 since port 80 is used by mssql server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [wamp server does not start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637779/wamp-server-does-not-start)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply go to `wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\bin` and look for `php.ini` find "`extension=php_mssql.dll`" edit it by place ; before the line like this "`;extension=php_mssql.dll`" restart the wamp and you are done!